# Ms Access formula to define Time-Shift based on Time Entered in a Cell

Tags: ms-access-2007

i have one cell (TimeOut) as Time (Short Time Format, 24 Hrs)
i have another cell (ShiftName) Text Filed
Required formula as below

```
     if Me.TimeOut >=6.00 and <= 14.00 Then
     Me.shiftName = "Morning Shift"
     Else If Me.TimeOut >= 14.01 and <= 22.00 then 
     Me.ShiftMane = "Afternoon Shift"
     Else 
     Me.ShiftName = "Night Shift"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time is not numbers, so try:

```vb
Select Case Me!TimeOut.Value
    Case < #06.00#
        Me!ShiftName = "Night Shift"
    Case <= #14.00#
        Me!ShiftName = "Morning Shift"
    Case <= #22.00# 
        Me!ShiftMane = "Afternoon Shift"
    Case Else 
        Me!ShiftName = "Night Shift"
End Select
```